# Cannot map through Dynamic: No instance for (Functor (Dynamic Spider))

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs, reflex, reflex-dom

My intention is to alternate the colour of a `div` between bright red and dark
red as a button gets pressed, starting with dark red.

I have this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    OverloadedStrings
  #-}

module Main where

import Data.Map (Map)
import Reflex.Dom

main = mainWidget $ do
    x <- greenButton
    y <- toggle False x
    let z = fmap style y
    elDynAttr "div" z blank

style :: Bool -> Map String String
style b | b         = "style" =: "height: 10ex; width: 10ex; background-color: #f00;"
        | otherwise = "style" =: "height: 10ex; width: 10ex; background-color: #900;"

greenButton :: MonadWidget t m => m (Event t ())
greenButton = button "[ ]"  -- Should be green but whatever.
```

It errors out thus:

```
• No instance for (Functor (Dynamic Spider))
    arising from a use of ‘fmap’
• In the expression: fmap style y
  In an equation for ‘z’: z = fmap style y
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘do { x <- greenButton;
          y <- toggle False x;
          let z = fmap style y;
          elDynAttr "div" z blank }’
```

I certainly see an `fmap` for `Dynamic` in the [quick reference](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/blob/develop/Quickref.md),
though I am not sure the version of the reference and the version of the
`reflex` package I compile against are consistent.

This is the `stack.yaml` I use for building:

```
resolver: lts-7.19
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1
compiler-check: match-exact

setup-info:
  ghcjs:
    source:
      ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1:
           url: http://ghcjs.tolysz.org/ghc-8.0-2017-02-05-lts-7.19-9007019.tar.gz
           sha1: d2cfc25f9cda32a25a87d9af68891b2186ee52f9

extra-deps:
- reflex-dom-0.3
- ghcjs-dom-0.2.4.0
- ref-tf-0.4.0.1
- reflex-0.4.0.1

allow-newer: true
```

What am I doing wrong? And who the hell is this guy Spider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion below explains why `Functor` for `Dynamic` turned out to be a bad idea.

https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/pull/39

> The problem with this instance is that it will evaluate `f` twice whenever the input dynamic changes: once to compute the new `Event` value, and once to compute the new `Behavior` value. With `mapDyn`, there is only a single computation, the result of both is shared. This is also why `mapDyn` is monadic.

---

So the code would look like this:

```
main = mainWidget $ do
    x <- greenButton
    y <- toggle False x
    z <- mapDyn style y      -- monadic mapDyn instead of fmap
    elDynAttr "div" z blank
```

---

On the issue of documentation, [`Quickref.md` for version `0.4.0.1` is here](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/blob/v0.4.0.1/Quickref.md) and only references `mapDyn`.

The `Quickref.md` you linked to is the one for the future `reflex-0.5` (the current `develop` branch), which is reworking `Dynamic` to have a `Functor` instance. [See their wiki](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/wiki/Reflex-FAQ):

> #### Why doesn't Dynamic have Functor/Applicative/Monad instances
>
> Reflex is scheduled to get these instances in version 0.5. As of this writing the implementation is mostly complete and is undergoing final polish and testing before release and is currently available on github in reflex's develop branch.

Comment: Oh. So why did they not fix the Quickref? It's been 2 years. I guess I should post an issue.

Comment: Probably an oversight.

Comment: It will be easier for me to accept your answer if you could expand it somewhat. One thing that would be helpful to a future reader is an example of working code. Also, it would be great if you refer to the [issue](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/issues/187) that I created, in case there will be answers from the maintainers, so that the answer stays up to date. I could edit the question myself, but it is questionable practice to significantly expand other people's answers, and some of the reviewers may vote against the edit.

Comment: Okay I added a bit more meat. It turns out the doc question is not an oversight, but that the linked `Quickref.md` is for a version of `reflex` under development.

Comment: For the record, I don't mind edits by other people to improve my answers, and otherwise I welcome requests to do so if you don't feel confident about it.

Comment: The problem is that some picky reviewers mind these edits if they are too massive and add substantial content of their own. I will keep your will in mind, but I would rather stick to asking you to expand your posts rather than doing so myself.

Comment: I see. That is fine too.